# Pending edits for the [china] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The community's views are sought on two related suggested edits for the [china](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china) tag:

The suggested "wiki" edit is:

> The [“Two Chinas” phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Chinas) makes this tag ambiguous.

And for the "tag wiki excerpt":

> Use [prc](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prc) (People’s Republic of China, “mainland China”) or [roc](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roc) (Republic of China, “Taiwan”) instead, unless a historic predecessor like the Republic of China (1912 – 1949) is meant, or in the event the PRC and ROC reunite.

I'm unsure what to do with these - approve, improve or reject.

But I am leaning towards rejecting them as it seems to me that, despite the suggestions being technically correct, "China" and "Taiwan" are the more recognisable and commonly use terms, especially in English.

Indeed, China's [UK embassy](http://gb.china-embassy.gov.cn/eng/) and Taiwan's [Taipei Representative Office in the UK](https://www.roc-taiwan.org/uk/index.html) both use the shortened versions within their text and menu options indicating that they are acceptable by the respective governments.

Note that [roc](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roc) or [prc](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prc) tags have not been created, presumably pending the outcome of the suggested edits - but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My vote is to use `china` and `taiwan`, make `prc` and `roc` synonyms for those, and update the wikis and guidance accordingly.

Comment: I've done the edits, but I don't have the required score to create the proposed synonyms.  [status-completed]..?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with feetwet, but specifically because this is standard practice in English and is also consistent with tag usage on other network sites. For example, Travel Stack Exchange uses [china](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china) and [taiwan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taiwan) tags as well as Politics Stack Exchange ([china](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china) and [taiwan](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taiwan)).

Beyond the Stack Exchange network, this is standard usage among English speakers. Regardless of what either government wants, the word "China" in common discourse means the People's Republic of China.